# How to change DropDown text color of picker in the .NetMaui

Tags: .net, maui, maui-windows, maui-community-toolkit

It's seem by default, dropdown text's color of picker in .Netmaui seem to be set as Black; Please tell me how to change it (it's best if can set the color bindable).

I already try to set this in Project/Platforms/Windows/App.xaml file:

`

```
<maui:MauiWinUIApplication
    ...
    <maui:MauiWinUIApplication.Resources>
        <SolidColorBrush x:Key="ComboBoxDropDownForceground" Color="#464E51" />
    </maui:MauiWinUIApplication.Resources>
</maui:MauiWinUIApplication>
```

`
but it's fail to change text's color of the dropdown.

Comment: which "DropDown" control are you talking about?  Do you mean the `Picker`?

Comment: *"but it's fail to change text's color of the dropdown."* What that declaration does is define a SolidColorBrush that **could** be used somewhere. It doesn't affect anything by itself. Does the picker have any Property that sounds like it might control this color? If so, put in your picker XAML: `... SomePropertyNameHere="{StaticResource ComboBoxDropDownForeground}" ...`.

Answer (score 0):

This is one of those rare occasions when ToolmakerSteve is incorrect.

You only need to specify the correct key for your resources and the Maui picker will automatically use them (as long as the following markup is placed in the platform/windows/app.xaml)

```
    <maui:MauiWinUIApplication
        ...
        <maui:MauiWinUIApplication.Resources>
            <!-- Background Color of Dropdown (Picker) -->
            <SolidColorBrush x:Key="ComboBoxDropDownBackground" Color="#777777" />
            <!-- TextColor of Dropdown (Picker) -->
            <SolidColorBrush x:Key="ComboBoxItemForeground" Color="#FFFFFF" />
        </maui:MauiWinUIApplication.Resources>
    </maui:MauiWinUIApplication>
```